# Cumulative Density Function for a variable that it's probability should increase while the random variable value increases

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-modeling, probability-density, usage-statistics

Let's say I have a variable and plot a histogram of it. Turns out the histogram looks like a exponentially decreasing curve.

The highest probability will be arround the values where the most frequent events happened. For me this is not what I'm looking for because the less probability the PDF is giving me it represents that I need to have a higher probability than the most frequent events.

If I fit a distribution and get the CDF looks like I'm getting what I want.

Now let's say I have another feature more and have the same tendency where the less probability the PDF is giving me I need to have a higher probability and then fit a PDF and get the CDF.

From these two probability values I need to get one. What are the methos for calculating this unique probability value. I thought: multiplying the 2 probabilities and a weighted sum (One of these 2 features has more relevance).

Comment: I did not understand your question. Perhaps rephrase it?

Comment: I agree with @Sartorius... Could you please provide an example?

Comment: For example: The three features, if I plot histograms of each of them it is shown that follows a right skewed distribution. As we move to the right in the 'x' axis I'm getting a lower and lower probability according to these distributions but for me the higher feature value that means there is more probability that a given example is classified '1'. I thought that getting the cumulative of these distributions can help me with this.